# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

Tags: angularjs, angular2-forms

I am using angular 2 forms in my application and i have created the input based on my model. I have binded my input field with ngmodel and now I want to do a dirty check on this input field. So i have added input with # variable. Here is my code:-

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: sampledetails.rules[0].query3.dirty}" class="form-control" name="query3" id="query3" [(ngModel)]="sampledetails.rules[0].query3" #query3="ngModel">
```

But I am getting an error something like:-

```
 There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("="form-control" name="query3" id="query3" [(ngModel)]="sampledetails.rules[0].query3" [ERROR ->]#query3="ngModel">
```

Can anybody help me here..

Comment: Have you imported FormsModule in your NgModule?

Comment: Yeah I have imported that.. here it is @NgModule({
  imports: [
 BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,RouterModule
  ],

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `#query3="ngModel"` for angular.js 2,
so change 
from

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: sampledetails.rules[0].query3.dirty}" 
    class="form-control" name="query3" id="query3" 
    [(ngModel)]="sampledetails.rules[0].query3" #query3="ngModel">
```

to (this will work)

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{red: sampledetails.rules[0].query3.dirty}" 
    class="form-control" name="query3" id="query3" 
    [(ngModel)]="sampledetails.rules[0].query3" >
```